# Updating Craft from Terminal

Tags: craft3, docker

I have a Craft 3 docker container. Craft is on version 3.7.44.

I log into the container with: `docker exec -it [container id] /bin/sh`

In the container I run: `php craft update`

Output:

> Fetching available updates ... done You’ve got 9 available updates:
>
> ```
> - craft 3.7.44 => 3.7.61
> - blitz 3.12.4 => 3.12.7
> - formie 1.6.10 => 1.6.20
> - image-optimize 1.6.44 => 1.6.49
> - redactor 2.10.8 => 2.10.10
> - retour 3.1.73 => 3.2.7
> - seomatic 3.4.32 => 3.4.45
> - super-table 2.7.2 => 2.7.3
> - vite 1.0.25 => 1.0.28
> ```
>
> Run craft update all or craft update  to perform an update.

I then run: `php craft update craft`

Output:

> Fetching available updates ... done Performing one update:
>
> ```
> - craft 3.7.44 => 3.7.61
> ```
>
> Create database backup? (yes|no) [yes]:no Skipping database backup.
> Performing update with Composer ... PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(/app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilesystemRepository.php
> on line 163 PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(/app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilesystemRepository.php
> on line 163 PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(/app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilesystemRepository.php
> on line 163 PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(/app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilesystemRepository.php
> on line 163 PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(/app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilesystemRepository.php
> on line 163 PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(/app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilesystemRepository.php
> on line 163 PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(/app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /app/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilesystemRepository.php
> on line 163 done Applying new migrations ... done Update complete!

If I run: `php craft update` again I see that there are no more Craft updates available.

However in the website backend I still see that there are Craft updates available and the backend in the footer still says version `3.7.44`.

Running `git status` shows that 2 files have been changed:

composer.lock
composer.json

composer.json:

```
 "name": "craft-cms",
    "description": "Project for Craft CMS",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        **"craftcms/cms": "3.7.61"**,
        "craftcms/redactor": "2.10.8",
        "mmikkel/cp-field-inspect": "1.4.4",
        "nystudio107/craft-emptycoalesce": "1.0.6",
        "nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize": "1.6.44",
        "nystudio107/craft-retour": "3.1.73",
        "nystudio107/craft-seomatic": "3.4.32",
        "nystudio107/craft-vite": "1.0.25",
        "putyourlightson/craft-blitz": "3.12.4",
        "putyourlightson/craft-sprig": "1.13.0",
        "sebastianlenz/linkfield": "1.0.25",
        "verbb/formie": "1.6.10",
        "verbb/super-table": "2.7.2",
        "yiisoft/yii2-redis": "^2.0",
        "zircote/swagger-php": "^4.2"
    },
```

**Update 1:**

If I run the Craft updates through the CMS backend, i.e. if I log into the website and navigate to Utilities > Updates and I click on "Update" then it works as expected. Craft is updated to version 3.7.61 and both the composer.json and composer.lock files are updated.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further testing it seems that the updates work fine. Despite these strange errors. Not sure if others have experienced this too. It is a little worrying to see errors during an update process. But doesn't seem to have an impact. Perhaps some issues to do with composer?

Comment: I don't know why that error occurs, but a viable workaround could be to not use Craft's built-in `update` command at all (it uses a bundled version of Composer, which seems related to the errors you get) – instead, update using Composer directly: First do a `composer update` inside the container to update any and all Composer dependencies, then run `php craft migrate/all` (also inside the container) to run any pending migrations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will test that.